# Why do my owl-items have width=0px

Tags: css, owl-carousel

I'm having an issue with owl-carousel when I try and incorporate it with a website, although it works fine in my standalone prototype. Essentially the `owl-wrapper` and all `owl-item` instances have a width set to 0 inline, and I can't work out why.

If I manually remove the width off these items it doesn't fix the carousel (although I'm not sure I expected it too). I'm using a fairly basic setup of owl-carousel:

```
// Setup the owl-carousel slider once the document has loaded
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#owl-slider").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 5000, //Set AutoPlay to 5 seconds
        singleItem: true,
        lazyLoad: true,
        lazyEffect: false
    });
})
```

If you visit [this page](http://innovia.netcprev.co.uk/) you can search for `owl-slider` in the DOM and see this output which is obviously wrong:

[image]

I've tried various things, lazy loading images, using lorem pixel instead of the embedded images but can't seem to fix the site. Yet I have a perfectly working prototype [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IPWright83/0c9h8hrj/) here. Can anyone provide me with a solution or some suggestions on things to continue trying?

Comment: Your fiddle works fine?  My guess is you've set display none on something which means your slider isn't calculating the widths properly when it is loaded (as the width of a display none item will be 0)

Comment: @Pete I've included my JSFiddle in the question too - As far as I'm aware I'm not explicitly setting anything like that. Removing the width 0 from all those elements displays the images (but in a vertical layout as the wrapper's width is wrong).

Comment: Try taking `float:left` off `.sliderBox`.

Comment: @Pete: I've tried retrospectively on the site I linked too - which doesn't fit it, and I don't believe that could affect the owl-carousel calculation?

Comment: I had a look at the site and I think because the div is floated left it is causing the calculation of everything inside it to be zero when the js runs - [see this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0c9h8hrj/1/).  I'm not sure why the sliderBox needs to be floated left as there isn't anything either side of it.  If it does need to be floated then give it a width.  Ps say hi to adj and chris for me!

Comment: @Pete: That surprises me, but does indeed fix the issue. Would you like to add as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: It's about settings container width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that using `float:left` on the owl carousel containing div `.sliderBox` is causing your issue.

Removing this style or setting a width for the `.sliderBox` div should fix your problem.